# How to replace string in original file with string from new file in Python

Tags: python

I have an original config file that has a string:

```
boothNumber="5"
```

In my program, I grab a similar config from another computer.  This similar config has a string:

```
boothNumber="1"
```

I want to read the new number which is 1 and replace the original config with the number 1(replaces 5).

I am getting an error in my program that says:

```
TypeError: coercing to str: need a bytes-like object, NoneType found
```

Any ideas?

```
import os
import shutil
import fileinput
import pypyodbc
import re                                     # used to replace string
import sys                                    # prevents extra lines being inputed in config


def readconfig(servername):
    destsource = 'remote.config'                                            # file that I grabbed from remote computer
    template = 'original.config'                                        # original config
    for line in open(destsource):                                       # open new config
        match = re.search(r'(?<=boothNumber=")\d+', line)               #find a number after a certain string and name it 'match'

        with fileinput.FileInput(template, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:  # open original config
            for f2line in file:
                pattern = r'(?<=boothNumber=")\d+'                      # find number after certain string and name it 'pattern'


                if re.search(pattern, f2line):                          # if line has 'pattern'
                    sys.stdout.write(re.sub(pattern, match, f2line))    # replace 'pattern' number with number from 'match'
                    fileinput.close()



def copyfrom(servername):
    # copy config from server


    source = r'//' + servername + '/c$/configdirectory'
    dest = r"C:/myprogramdir"
    file = "remote.config"
    try:
        shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source, file), os.path.join(dest, file))
        # you can't just use shutil when copying from a remote computer.  you have to also use os.path.join
    except:
        copyerror()

    readconfig(servername)



os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
array = []
with open("serverlist.txt", "r") as f:       # list of computer names
    for servername in f:

        copyfrom(servername.strip())
```

Comment: Could you post the whole traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `readConfig` function, this line performs a search:

`match = re.search(r'(?<=boothNumber=")\d+', line)`

and the value of `match` is used in this line:

`sys.stdout.write(re.sub(pattern, match, f2line))`

There are two problems here. Firstly, if the search is unsuccessful `match` will be `None`, causing to the exception that you report:

```
 >>> re.sub(r'[a-z]+', None, 'spam')
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, NoneType found
```

Secondly, if `match` is not `None`, you are trying to use `match` itself as replacement string, but `match` is not a string, it's a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects):

```
>>> match = re.search(r'[a-z]+', 'spam')
>>> match
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='spam'>  # <=== not a string!
>>> re.sub(r'[a-z]+', match, 'eggs')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, _sre.SRE_Match found
```

You need to call `match.group()` to get the string that has been matched:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[a-z]+', match.group(), 'eggs')
'spam'
```

To summarise:

- condition the output processing on `match` not being `None`
- use `match.group()` as the replacement string